# Contains doesn't work as I expected

Tags: c#

I'm wondering why I cannot compare these objects:

```
public class myCustomClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<string> Keys { get; set; }
}
```

I receive a `List<myCustomClass>`

I created a `Comparer` and looks like

```
var comparer = new myCustomClass{
    Value = "somethingToCompare"
};
```

And when I do `MyList.Contains(comparer)` is `false`.

EDIT: `MyList` values have "somethingToCompare", but my comparer doesn't have keys so it's always false.

My question is, can I only compare if my value exists inside my List, without comparing my Keys?

Comment: What is attrOptions?

Comment: I Edit, is an List<myCustomClass>

Comment: what is MyQueryStringInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `MyQueryStringInfo` and `myCustomClass` are the same?

Either way you are trying to find an object with the `Value` of `"somethingToCompare"` right?

If this is the case, try this instead:

```
MyList.Any(item => item.Value == comparer.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently your class does not override `Equals`, so it's going to do reference equality and obviously the exact reference that `comparer` contains is not in your list.  If you only want to compare on one property you can use Linq's `Any` method.

```
var hasIt = MyList.Any(m => m.Value == comparer.Value);
```

It should be noted that even if you created `comparer` with `Keys` set to a list that contains the same strings in the same orders as the item in your `MyList`, `Contains` still would not return true because of it doing reference equality instead of value equality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with a "User" object:

```
List<User> usrs = new List<User>(); // assuming you have data
string emailToTest = "markAsAnswer@DevAffair.com";
bool valueExist = users.Where(x=>x.Email == emailToTest).Count() > 0;
```

Give it a shot

Comment: Using `.Where(x=>x.Email == emailToTest).Count()` is inefficient, it requires enumerating every item in the collection even if the first item is a match. `.Any(x=>x.Email == emailToTest)` would be a better solution to this as it stops after the first match.